# Angular2 appear warning XMLHttpRequest at chrome

Tags: rest, angular, http, xmlhttprequest

I used Http Restful API at Angular2, but appear the following warning message.

**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.**

Please tell me how to do that.

---

**http_restful_service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class HTTPRestfulService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getAllProjectName() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','charset=uft-8');
    return         
       this._http.get('http://localhost/api/database/',
                     {headers: headers})
                 .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**backstage_view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTPRestfulService } from './../../../service/http_restful_service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'backstage_view',
    templateUrl: './backstage_view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./backstage_view.component.css']
})

export class BackstageViewComponent implements OnInit {

    allProjects: string;

    constructor(private _restfulapi: HTTPRestfulService) {}

    ngOnInit() {     
      this._restfulapi.getAllProjectName()
                      .subscribe(
                        data => this.allProjects = data,
                        error => console.log(error),
                      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you customized Http?

Comment: Posted code does not seem to be sync requests. are you using somewhere else?

Comment: @pixelbits no...

Comment: @Jai I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @NickHsu have you set this `async:false` anywhere?

Comment: @Jai no, I never set this.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you pass the content-type as 'application/json' format,

```
let url= `http://localhost/api/database/`;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    let params = new URLSearchParams;
    params.append('id', id);
    params.append('user_id', user_id);
    return this.authHttp.post( url,  { headers:headers,  search:params })
   .map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: I forget it, thank you. 
But my problem has not been solved yet.